# Lifting clopen subsets

Tags: gn.general-topology

> Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $T$, we say that clopen subset of $A$ lift to $T$ whenever  $L$  is a clopen subset of $A$ the there exists a clopen subset $H$ of $T$ such that $H\cap A=L$.

Now let $X$ be a compact and $T_0$-space and $Y$ and $Z$ be two closed subsets of $X$  whose  clopen subsets  lift to $X$. Is there any condition under which the clopen subsets of $Y\cap Z$  lift to $T$? and is there any condition under which the clopen subsets of  $Y\cup Z $ lift to $T$

Comment: What about the case of finite $T_0$-spaces? Is everything clear in this case?